# How to use NSwag.CodeGeneration.CSharp?

Tags: nswag

I am trying to generate .NET Core Web API Controllers from a .yaml file.

There is an example of running this command:

```
dotnet "/.../dotnet-nswag.dll" openapi2cscontroller /input:https://somewhere.com/swagger.yaml /classname:MyResource /namespace:Com.Example.MyResource /output:Controllers/ResourceController.cs /UseLiquidTemplates:true /AspNetNamespace:"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" /ControllerBaseClass:"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller"
```

How is this command relates to NSwag.CodeGeneration.CSharp ?

Whats is this parameter?  `"/.../dotnet-nswag.dll"` Is this coming from npm install of the tools?

How can i generate ApiControllers on my Spec project build in Visual Studio?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The actual implementation of the generator is in the NSwag.CodeGeneration.CSharp nuget package.

You can use this directly in you code to programmatically read a spec and generate code to a string. dotnet-nswag.dll is a command line tool with commands which translate to a call to a generator in this package.

Answer (score 2):

For commandline usage with dotnet cli, simpliest options is just execute run command passing as argument the nswag configuration file with the required settings for the source code generation.

```
dotnet C:\Users\demo\.nuget\packages\nswag.msbuild\13.4.2\tools\NetCore31\dotnet-nswag.dll run config.nswag
NSwag command line tool for .NET Core NetCore31, toolchain v13.4.2.0 (NJsonSchema v10.1.11.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0))
Visit http://NSwag.org for more information.
NSwag bin directory: C:\Users\demo\.nuget\packages\nswag.msbuild\13.4.2\tools\NetCore31

Executing file 'config.nswag' with variables ''...
Done.

Duration: 00:00:01.8555952
```

Or you can use additional commands like the one you posted (openapi2cscontroller) detailed in the wiki
https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/CommandLine